# Magento translate text within jquery script

Tags: jquery, magento

Does anybody know how I can translate below text with the normal .csv translate option?

The text that needs to be translated is the Price From:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".cnf .price-box .price").each(function(){
        var pr  =   jQuery(this).html();
        jQuery(this).html('<span style="font-weight:normal;color:#000;font-    size: 12px;">Price From:</span>'+pr);
    });
});
```

I think it's an issue with my custom magento module. I have added the following to my etc/config.xml

```
<translate>
        <modules>
            <Magextension_Sdocp>
                <files>
                    <default>Magextension_Sdocp.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Magextension_Sdocp>
        </modules>
    </translate>
```

Problem is when I use Inline translation he is saying something different but the scope is correct I think

http://i61.tinypic.com/2q8ugs9.png

After the answer from Suman I tried

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".cnf .price-box .price").each(function(){
    var pr  =   jQuery(this).html();
    jQuery(this).html('<span style="font-weight:normal;color:#000;font-    size:      12px;"><?php echo $this->__('Price From') ?>:</span>'+pr);
});
});
```

and

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".cnf .price-box .price").each(function(){
    var pr  =   jQuery(this).html();
   jQuery(this).html('<span style="font-weight:normal;color:#000;font-size:12px;"><?php        echo $this->__('Price From') ?>:</span>'+pr);
});
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".cnf .price-box .price").each(function(){
        var pr  =   jQuery(this).html();
        jQuery(this).html('<span style="font-weight:normal;color:#000;font-    size:      12px;"><?php echo $this->__('Price From') ?>:</span>'+pr);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for me :-( I updated my question with more information maybe this can help?